# c++ undefined references with static library

Tags: c++, static-libraries

I'm trying to make a static library from a class but when trying to use it, I always get errors with undefined references on anything. The way I proceeded was creating the object file like

```
g++ -c myClass.cpp -o myClass.o
```

and then packing it with

```
ar rcs myClass.lib myClass.o
```

There is something I'm obviously missing generally with this. I bet it's something with symbols.
Thanks for any advice, I know it's most probably something I could find out if reading some tutorial so sorry if bothering with stupid stuff again :)

### edit:

myClass.h:

```
class myClass{
    public:
        myClass();
        void function();
};
```

myClass.cpp:

```
#include "myClass.h"

myClass::myClass(){}
void myClass::function(){}
```

program using the class:

```
#include "myClass.h"

int main(){
myClass mc;
mc.function();

return 0;
}
```

finally I compile it like this:

```
g++ -o main.exe -L. -l myClass main.cpp
```

the error is just classic:

```
C:\Users\RULERO~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ccwM3vLy.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x31): undefined
 reference to `myClass::myClass()'
C:\Users\RULERO~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ccwM3vLy.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x3c): undefined
 reference to `myClass::function()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/409470/6064933

Answer (score 159, accepted):

This is *probably* a link order problem.  When the GNU linker sees a library, it discards all symbols that it doesn't need.  In this case, your library appears before your .cpp file, so the library is being discarded before the .cpp file is compiled.  Do this:

```
g++ -o main.exe main.cpp -L. -lmylib
```

or

```
g++ -o main.exe main.cpp myClass.lib
```

The Microsoft linker doesn't consider the ordering of the libraries on the command line.

Comment: Don't.  This catches all kinds of developers out.  I probably spent a week trying to figure out strange linker problems in a large project that turned out to be this issue.

Comment: You're my hero of the day! :) I spent an hour sitting in front of an undefined reference linker error to find out that it is this simple mistake. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Thanks a bunch, just came across this thread having the same problem, and it pretty much solved the issue for me too! :)

Comment: Even in cmake framework under linux, it appeared that order inside th target_link_libraries() do matters. Thank you a lot for this indication that saved me a lot of time !

Comment: Even in the bottom half of 2015, this is still highly relevant!

Comment: Eleven years later, you saved my day. Many thanks. Both Windows and macOS linkers don't consider the ordering of the libraries. Only Linux..

Answer (score 42):

Another possible cause: forgetting `extern "C"`.

I ran into this because I was trying to link a C++ program with a C static library. The library's header didn't have `extern "C"` so the linker was looking for a mangled function name, and the library actually had the unmangled function name.

It took a while to figure out what was going on, so I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Thank you, that saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 11):

This is an issue how the linker optimizes the output code. 
Lets assume we have an executable that uses two libraries: **Lib_A** and **Lib_B**. **Lib_A** depends on **Lib_B**
The **Lib_A** defines symbols: *Lib_A1* and *Lib_A2*, and the **Lib_B** defines symbol *Lib_B1* and *Lib_B2*. 
Now lets assume that the executable uses only symbol *Lib_A1*, and *Lib_A1* uses symbol *Lib_B1* which is defined in **Lib_B**. Symbol *Lib_B1* is never used in the executable.

1. In case of windows, the linker works like this: I have executable with two which uses some libs and all symbols used in executable and all libs are *lib_A1* and *lib_B1*. Thus I will need these two symbols, and the rest is unnecessary. I will undefine *lib_A2* and *lib_B2*
2. In case of linux if you link **Lib_B** before **Lib_A** like this:
   `g++ .... -lLib_B -lLib_A`
   The linker works like this: I have executable that first links **Lib_B**. I do not see that the executable uses symbol *Lib_B1* nor *Lib_B2*. They are unnecesary, thus I will undefine them. Later the linker see. Oh I have another library **Lib_A**. I can see that executable uses symbol *Lib_B1*. I will keep it and undefine unused symbol *Lib_B2*. It does not see that *Lib_B1* uses *Lib_A1*, Which is already undefined.
3. In case of linux if you link **Lib_A** before **Lib_B** like this:
   `g++ ... -lLib_A -lLib_B`
   The linker works like this: I have executable that first links **Lib_A**. Oh, I can see that executable uses *Lib_A1*. I will keep them and undefine *Lib_A2*. Later it can see. Oh I have another library **Lib_B**. I can see that now executable with already linked symbols, uses *Lib_B1*, I will keep them. As a result it keeps *Lib_B1* and *Lib_A1*, and undefined *Lib_B2* and *Lib_A2*.

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
g++ -o main.exe main.cpp myClass.lib
```

Using the library path and the -l flag is fraught with problems, but if you must do it, rename your library to libmylib.a and then compile as:

```
g++ -o main.exe main.cpp -L. -lmylib
```

Note also that for portability reasons, it's generally a bad idea to use mixed case in the names of source or output files.

Comment: yea I heard about recommended names for libraries.. but i already found out the error looks differentely if the library can't be linked.. so i would say that ain't the sollution in this case. and you don't need to hesitate calling me stupid_idiot ;)

Comment: I always forget the link order matters with g++ - every time :-(

Answer (score -3):

This should avoid linking errors and create the .so shared library:

```
LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS := true
```

Comment: would not this just deffer problem to runtime ?