# undefined refrence link error static library cross compiling for beagle bone black

Tags: c++, linker, embedded, arm, cross-compiling

Cross compiling for Beagle Bone Black on my centos machine.

Im creating an application 'BasicComponentsTest.cpp' which uses the 'SimFrameProducer' class that I've created and built into a static library i.e. 'libspu.a'. see below makefile and code for reference.

I get link error when compiling the main application using the 'libspu.a' statically link a library, however it works fine when I link the objects directly (see direct object makefile) i.e. it only fails when compiling with the static library that I created, obviously the the SPU object compile fine and creates the static library file 'libspu.a'.

The only thing I can think that might be wrong is the 'ar' command does not work properly for cross compiled objects, is this correct? is there any other reason why I get this error? BTW I'm still new to c++.

```
[root@CVDEV SPU]# make
make: Warning: File `Makefile' has modification time 3.6e+04 s in the future
/opt/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.8-2014.04_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ -Wall -I ../../SPU/Include -L ../../SPU -lspu BasicComponentsTest.cpp -o Test1
/tmp/cc6Ck7Xj.o: In function `main':
BasicComponentsTest.cpp:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `SimFrameProducer::SimFrameProducer(char*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
[root@CVDEV SPU]#
```

BasicCompontentsTest.cpp main application file

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include "SimFrameProducer.h"
using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    SimFrameProducer* prod = new SimFrameProducer((char*)"Test1");

    prod->Start();
    prod->Stop();

    delete prod;

    return 0;
}
```

SimFrameProducer.h

```
#include "SPUBase.h"
#include "SPUFrameProducer.h"

class SimFrameProducer:public SPUFrameProducer, public SPUBase {
public:
    SimFrameProducer(char* instanceId);
    virtual ~SimFrameProducer();
    void Start();
    void Stop();
private:

};
```

SimFrameProducer.cpp

```
#include "SimFrameProducer.h"
#include "Include/SimFrameProducer.h"


SimFrameProducer::SimFrameProducer(char* instanceId):SPUBase((char*)"TYPE_SAMPLE", instanceId) {

}

void SimFrameProducer::Start(){

}

void SimFrameProducer::Stop(){

}

SimFrameProducer::~SimFrameProducer() {

}
```

Makefile main BasicComponentsTest application

```
CC=/opt/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.8-2014.04_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
SPU_PATH=../../SPU
INC=-I $(SPU_PATH)/Include
LIB=-L $(SPU_PATH)

all: 
    $(CC) -Wall $(INC) $(LIB) -lspu BasicComponentsTest.cpp -o Test1
```

Makefile linking direct object instead of static library

```
CC=/opt/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.8-2014.04_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
SPU_PATH=../../SPU
INC=-I $(SPU_PATH)/Include
LIB=-L $(SPU_PATH)

OBJS=$(SPU_PATH)/SPUBase.o \
$(SPU_PATH)/SPUFrame.o \
$(SPU_PATH)/SPUFrameProducer.o \
$(SPU_PATH)/FFTFrameProducer.o \
$(SPU_PATH)/SimFrameProducer.o

## Target: all
all: 
    $(CC) -Wall $(INC) $(OBJS) BasicComponentsTest.cpp -o Test1
```

Makefile for SPU lib

```
CC=/opt/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.8-2014.04_linux/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
INC=-I Include
## Target: all
all: 
    $(CC) -Wall $(INC) -c SPUBase.cpp
    $(CC) -Wall $(INC) -c SPUFrame.cpp
    $(CC) -Wall $(INC) -c SPUFrameProducer.cpp
    $(CC) -Wall $(INC) -c FFTFrameProducer.cpp
    $(CC) -Wall $(INC) -c SimFrameProducer.cpp
    ar cr libspu.a SPUBase.o SPUFrame.o SPUFrameProducer.o FFTFrameProducer.o SimFrameProducer.o
```

Comment: The archive utility `ar` does little more that combine multiple files into a single file.  That is not the cause of your problem.

Given the make file  your static library must be `../../SPU/libspu.a` - is that the case?

Comment: yes, i do not get file not found error in the compile/link

Comment: Why are you not using the ar command supplied with your cross toolchain? Even if your host ar has support for your target architecture (does it?), it may be of a different version than your cross ar.

Answer (score 0):

Your archive lacks an *object-file index*.  The `ar` command line should be:

`ar rcs libspu.a SPUBase.o SPUFrame.o SPUFrameProducer.o FFTFrameProducer.o SimFrameProducer.o`

You were missing the `s` option, making your archive just a collection of files in a file (an archive - ar is not just for libraries - though that is invariably what it is used for) rather than a *library*.

Comment: I have tried you suggestion, but i still get the same problem.

Comment: it is running on a NFS share from a windows 8 machine, could that be a problem?

Comment: @BerabenSystems : Seems unlikely as it has accessed the header file in the same path.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem it was the order of where I put the static library when building it, apparently the static library was excluded because it was perceived by the compiler as not used, when you put it after the c++ file it realizes that it needs it and uses it. 
All credits to this post

[c++ undefined references with static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624238/c-undefined-references-with-static-library)

Changed my code to the following to get it to work

```
$(CC) -Wall -o Test1 $(INC) $(LIB)  BasicComponentsTest.cpp -lspu
```