# Problems linking static library to c++ project with MinGW

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, static-libraries

**Edit:** ***Sorry I realize there must have been some misunderstanding when posting this question, I want to specify that I DO realize this question was asked a few times, none of the answers work for me however***

I've been trying to link a simple static library test to one of my c++ projects, but I can't seem to get it quite right. I know that this is a very widespread topic and that a lot of people have already asked a similar question, but even after reading some of the answers, I still cannot, for the love of god, figure out what I am doing wrong.

My code is very simple, first I have a .cpp source file titled "Math.cpp" that looks like this:

```
#include "Math.h"

int max(int a, int b) {

    return a > b ? a : b;

}
int min(int a, int b) {

    return a < b ? a : b;

}
int floor(double a) {

    return (int) a;

}
int ceil(double a) {

    return (int) a + 1;

}
```

..And to go with that I made a header file called "Math.h" that looks like this:

```
#pragma once

int max(int, int);
int min(int, int);
int floor(double);
int ceil(double);
```

I then compile "Math.cpp" with the following command on cmd:

```
g++ -c Math.cpp -o Math.o
```

...and then compile it into a static library like so:

```
ar rcs libMath.a Math.o
```

After all of this I make a new c++ soure file titled "Main.cpp" that looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Math.h"

int main() {

    std::cout << max(9, 8) << std::endl;
    return 0;

}
```

("Math.h" is in the same directory as "Main.cpp")

So finally in order to link "Main.cpp" with my static library ("libMath.a"), I use the following command in cmd:

```
g++ -o Main.exe Main.cpp -L. -lMath
```

however, at this point, it throws the following error:

```
C:\Users\zalmar\AppData\Local\Temp\ccmOnvyg.o:Main.cpp:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `max(int, int)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

... I cannot figure out why it can't find the reference to the specific function. Some people appeared to have the same problem ([here for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624238/c-undefined-references-with-static-library)). Their solution was to declare the Main.cpp source file before declaring the library path. However, that was not the case for me, even though I made sure I was linking the library after the Main.cpp it still came up with the same error. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could point out anything I might be doing wrong because clearly I must be doing something wrong. Otherwise it might be a problem with my MinGW compiler, maybe?

I also want to re-mention that this is just a test library and I am fully aware that it might be a bit overkill to compile an entire static library from such a simple program. I am simply trying to figure out how to link libraries to my c++ projects...

Comment: Can't reproduce. Is it **your actual code**? In error message there is `int max<int>(int, int)`, but you don't have templates in your code.

Comment: I can't reproduce either.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, I changed my code previously and forgot to change its respective error. The linker still, however, threw the same error with undefined reference to `max(int, int)`. This is the **Exact** code I am using...

Comment: @BobMorane, If it is as you say, and you guys can't reproduce this error, then would you say it's a problem with the linker all together? Maybe should I reinstall MinGW? Afterall, I am using a pretty old versioin of MinGW.

Comment: @Xamser7 I compiled and linked your program using `g++` and `ar` with your exact code and shell commands on Linux and have had no problem. It links and runs fine. I'm not sure about MinGW, but in your position I would certainly start trying to reproduce it with different compilers/linkers/environments and try to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @BobMorane I am using windows 7 and windows 10 to do all of this, would that be the problem?

Comment: @Xamser7 I'm not sure. Have you tried doing the same thing with the Microsoft compiler/linker?

Comment: What's output of `g++ --version`? It works on my MinGW-w64 (GCC 7.3.0), so you can download it if you want.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I am using MinGW-w64 also, but mine is (GCC 6.3.0). Do you know where I can get the newest version? Because [mingw.org](http://mingw.org/) just redirects me to the respective [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/) link, which only provides me with 6.3.0 for some reason.

Comment: There is big difference between MinGW-w64 and plain MinGW. [Here's a link for you](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win32/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/installer/mingw-w64-install.exe/download). Also it's generally better to provide full output of `g++ --version` because it often says more than just the version number.