# C++ static library linking in a C project

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I am trying to statically link a C++ library to a C project but can't seem to figure a way out. I read multiple posts but nothing helped.
Below is the snippet of my Makefile:

```
 CFLAGS += -I../path/to/headers
 LIBS += ../path/to/lib.a
```

I get the below linking error:

```
"undefined reference to ...
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status"
```

I checked this post for ordering but I don't that is an issue here:
[c++ undefined references with static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624238/c-undefined-references-with-static-library)

I wanted to know if it is even possible. If so, what flags I would need to add into my C project Makefile.

Comment: you cannot direct link c++ into c, since the names would under name mangling. you can use `extern "C"` (or guess the mangled name :P )

Comment: In addition to @appleapple Guessing the mangled name is not that complicated. Once, code is compiled you may have a look into the object or library files (e.g. with `nm` on Linux). To bad that the name mangling is not standardized and depends on compiler/platform. I'm with appleapple for his/her better advice about `extern "C"`. Though, it has limitations as well as the marked variables and functions really must conform to C. (IMHO, for the latter fact there is no way out.)

Comment: And, is it applicable to both static and dynamic (using SO file instead of static) linking?

Comment: Could you show which references are unresolved? Are they expected to come from that C++ library?

Comment: These references are from my C++ library that I'm trying to integrate.  In the above example, it's just an function call. E.g. undefined reference to 'call_add', where call_add is a function declared in a header and implementation in some C++ file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the library that you pretend to link with is not prepared to export C compatible function names in the object code, you should add a C++/C bridge to your project.

This bridge may consist of a C++ header and source files where you write C++ code that uses the C++ library where the symbols that you need to use from your C program are exported in a C compatible way.

You should do something like this:

bridge.h

```
#include <cpplibrary.h>
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int bridge();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

bridge.cpp

```
#include "bridge.h"

extern "C" {
int bridge() {
CppLibrary *object = new CppLibrary();
return object->returnInt();
}

} // extern "C"
```

This C++ code is compiled exporting names that the C linker can understand, allowing to indirectly use the C++ code of that given library.