# linked .so has : undefined reference to `fminf'

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, undefined-reference, shared-objects

I have example.so, which uses fminf and fmaxf.
This code of example does include .

Now the problem is I am writing another sample.cpp code, in whose Makefile I have added 
    LDFLAGS += -lexample 
to use the APIs under it.

While making this code I get following link error.
../lib/example.so: undefined reference to `fminf'
../lib/example.so: undefined reference to`fmaxf'

However I tried adding

1. LDFLAGS += -lstdc++ -lm -lexample.
2. LDFLAGS += -lexample -lm -lstdc++.

Still both does not work and I get the same error.

Comment: Are you getting the error when building `example.so`, or when using the library? If it's when using the library, did you build the library with `-lm` when linking it? How did you build the library?

Comment: I am getting error while building sample.cpp.
   Where I have linked example.so.    example.so build fine and .so is created.

Comment: Might it be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2624238/c-undefined-references-with-static-library) ?

Comment: @moizh can you add output of `nm -D libexample.so | grep fminf` and `nm -D /path/to/libm.so | grep fminf`?

Comment: @NeilGatenby     I tried this linking order (as mentioned in description) but no luck.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude , Yes I have linked library (example.so) with -lm and so it was built successfully.
Problem is when using that library(.so) in some other place.

Comment: @keltar 
Command: nm -D libexample.so | grep fminf
Output:   U fminf

Comment: @moizh and the one in libm? It should be in e.g. `/lib/` or `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`. Also could you specify what's full resulting linking line is?

Comment: You missing a `#include <stdlib.h>` anywhere?